# Will Sphinx work with code that doesn't import well?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Will the Sphinx documentation engine successfully generate documentation on a project that doesn't import well?  In particular my project has an exotic dependency.  I don't want document generation to depend on this dependency.

Does Sphinx need to import my module and use introspection or does it parse?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the autodoc extension, then yes, your project must be importable. But sometimes it's possible to mock out dependencies in your `conf.py` (since, presumably, at the time of import, the dependencies are needed in name only). The Read the Docs documentation has an example of [how to do this](http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules).

Answer (score 1):

Core Sphinx doesn't touch your code at all. The [autodoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html) extension does, and it indeed imports it:

> For Sphinx (actually, the Python interpreter that executes Sphinx) to find your module, it must be importable.